# Index Zero issue with sql

Tags: c#, mysql

I keep running into a problem with my sql:

```
{ 
    Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)); 
    Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0)); 
}
```

Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero?

Not sure if its my String.Format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the second line should be again 0 for string.Format:

```
 Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be the second line of code

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));
```

The String.Format, is looking for 3 parameters in that case, {0}, {1} and finally {2}. You have only one.

You should write it has :

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the index for *SQL*, it's the index for `string.Format`. This should be evident in the stack trace, which will point to `string.Format` rather than `reader.GetString`. Looking carefully at stack traces can save you all manner of effort :)

Of course you don't really need to format at all here (given that you'll just end up with the input string), and I *suspect* you want column 2. (My guess is that that's where the error came from, after all.)

```
Aboutme.Text = reader.GetString(2);
```

If you really want to use `string.Format`:

```
Aboutme.Text = string.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution than that proposed by the accepted answer.  Note that the statement ...

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

... passes the format string and some string value to `String.Format`, which analyzes the format string, calls `ToString()` on the string value, and then inserts that value into the result at the position indicated by the sequence `{0}`.  Then, of course, it returns the constructed string as its result.  Because the format string is `"{0}"`, the constructed string will have the same value as the argument.

Both the written code and the executed algorithm will be simpler if you write this:

```
Aboutme.Text = reader.GetString(0);
```